# image link in drupal 6 content

Tags: php, javascript, css, html, drupal-6

```
.content_left_image{
 float:left; 
 width:746px;
 height:368px;
 padding-left:1px;
 background-position:right;
}

<div class="content_left_image">$src</div>
```

This div is used in drupal 6 content. & `$src` is image source... But image is not showed. i think i have problem in image src...my template name is codemen & image folder is in codemen folder...How can i show this image?

Comment: using firebug you can find from where the code tries to catch the image. According to this information change the path. Otherwise give us a live example to help you better.

Comment: i have used firebug but i can't solve this prob.                  <img src="codemen/images/slogan_people.png"  height="368px" width="746px">  here codemen is my template name for drupal 6. but image is not showed here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have this:

```
<div class="content_left_image">$src</div>
```

If yes, you should do this instead:

```
<div class="content_left_image"><?php print $src; ?></div>
```

I can't understand where are you writing this. If it's the body of a node, you should be able to view the image if the content type has PHP mode enabled. But where does `$src` come from? It is a placeholder you wrote just here?

I think I'm can't get something of your question.

Anyway, hope this helps.
—Alberto

Comment: <img src="codemen/images/slogan_people.png" height="368px" width="746px"> here codemen is my template name for drupal 6. but image is not showed here.

Comment: <img src="codemen/images/slogan_people.png" height="368px" width="746px"> here codemen is my template name for drupal 6. but image is not showed here.